# GCC12: No compila libcpp: cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C

Tags: c++, gcc, make

Compilando *GCC12*, no compila `libcpp`... Al parecer el problema es que trata a *C++* como si fuera *C*, pero eso sale como *warning* y no como *error*.

Desde aquí empiezan los errores:

> make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'
> `g++ -std=c++11  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include    -c -o charset.o -MT charset.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/charset.Tpo ../.././libcpp/charset.c`
> cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
> cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-fno-rtti’ is valid for C++/D/ObjC++ but not for C

```
In file included from ../.././libcpp/include/cpplib.h:27,
                 from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:22:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:330:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
  330 |   static source_range from_location (location_t loc)
      |   ^~~~~~
```

Error en `line-map.h:330`:

- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libcpp/include/line-map.h#L330

```c
/* We avoid using constructors, since various structs that
 don't yet have constructors will embed instances of
 source_range.  */

/* Make a source_range from a location_t.  */
static source_range from_location (location_t loc)
{
    source_range result;
    result.m_start = loc;
    result.m_finish = loc;
    return result;
}
```

El error en el *Makefile* es en esta línea ***Makefile:226*** del `libcpp`:

```
# Implicit rules and I18N

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)
```

Registro de lo ya compilado:

```sh
/gcc12/gcc make
[ -f stage_final ] || echo stage3 > stage_final
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
Making all in tests
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests'
Making all in .
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all-am'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests'
Making all in devel
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/devel'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/devel'
Making all in mpn
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpn'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpn'
Making all in mpz
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpz'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpz'
Making all in mpq
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpq'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpq'
Making all in mpf
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpf'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpf'
Making all in rand
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/rand'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/rand'
Making all in misc
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/misc'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/misc'
Making all in cxx
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/cxx'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/cxx'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tests'
Making all in mpn
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpn'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpn'
Making all in mpz
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpz'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpz'
Making all in mpq
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpq'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpq'
Making all in mpf
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpf'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/mpf'
Making all in printf
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/printf'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/printf'
Making all in scanf
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/scanf'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/scanf'
Making all in rand
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/rand'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/rand'
Making all in cxx
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/cxx'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/cxx'
Making all in demos
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos'
Making all in calc
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/calc'
make  all-am
make[7]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/calc'
make[7]: No se hace nada para 'all-am'.
make[7]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/calc'
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/calc'
Making all in expr
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/expr'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos/expr'
make[6]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos'
make[6]: No se hace nada para 'all-am'.
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/demos'
Making all in tune
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tune'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/tune'
Making all in doc
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/doc'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp/doc'
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr'
Making all in doc
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/doc'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/doc'
Making all in src
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/src'
make  all-am
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/src'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all-am'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/src'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/src'
Making all in tests
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/tests'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/tests'
Making all in tune
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/tune'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr/tune'
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all-am'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpfr'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
Making all in src
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/src'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/src'
Making all in tests
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/tests'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/tests'
Making all in doc
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/doc'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc/doc'
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mpc'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
Making all in .
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
Making all in doc
make[5]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl/doc'
make[5]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl/doc'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/isl'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/testsuite'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/testsuite'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
make  all-am
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/intl'
make[3]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/intl'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/testsuite'
make[4]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/testsuite'
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'
make[3]: No se hace nada para 'all'.
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'
```

Errores:

```sh
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'
g++ -std=c++11  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include    -c -o charset.o -MT charset.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/charset.Tpo ../.././libcpp/charset.c
cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-fno-rtti’ is valid for C++/D/ObjC++ but not for C
In file included from ../.././libcpp/include/cpplib.h:27,
                 from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:22:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:330:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
  330 |   static source_range from_location (location_t loc)
      |   ^~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:403:43: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘:’ token
  403 | struct GTY((tag ("1"))) line_map_ordinary : public line_map {
      |                                           ^
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:448:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
  448 | };
      |  ^
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:461:40: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘:’ token
  461 | struct GTY((tag ("2"))) line_map_macro : public line_map {
      |                                        ^
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:539:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
  539 | };
      |  ^
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:585:23: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  585 | MAP_ORDINARY_P (const line_map *map)
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: In function ‘MAP_ORDINARY_P’:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:587:30: error: request for member ‘start_location’ in something not a structure or union
  587 |   return IS_ORDINARY_LOC (map->start_location);
      |                              ^~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: At top level:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:593:38: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  593 | linemap_macro_expansion_map_p (const line_map *);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:599:8: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_ordinary’
  599 | inline line_map_ordinary *
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:600:25: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  600 | linemap_check_ordinary (line_map *map)
      |                         ^~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:610:14: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_ordinary’
  610 | inline const line_map_ordinary *
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:611:31: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  611 | linemap_check_ordinary (const line_map *map)
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:21:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: In function ‘linemap_check_ordinary’:
../.././libcpp/system.h:404:50: warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]
  404 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:547:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘abort’
  547 |       abort ();                                       \
      |       ^~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:613:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘linemap_assert’
  613 |   linemap_assert (MAP_ORDINARY_P (map));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../.././libcpp/include/cpplib.h:27,
                 from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:22:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:614:17: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_ordinary’
  614 |   return (const line_map_ordinary *)map;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: At top level:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:620:8: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_macro’
  620 | inline line_map_macro *linemap_check_macro (line_map *map)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:620:45: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  620 | inline line_map_macro *linemap_check_macro (line_map *map)
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:629:14: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_macro’
  629 | inline const line_map_macro *
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:630:28: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  630 | linemap_check_macro (const line_map *map)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:21:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: In function ‘linemap_check_macro’:
../.././libcpp/system.h:404:50: warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]
  404 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:547:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘abort’
  547 |       abort ();                                       \
      |       ^~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:632:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘linemap_assert’
  632 |   linemap_assert (!MAP_ORDINARY_P (map));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../.././libcpp/include/cpplib.h:27,
                 from ../.././libcpp/charset.c:22:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:633:17: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_macro’
  633 |   return (const line_map_macro *)map;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: At top level:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:639:27: error: unknown type name ‘line_map’
  639 | MAP_START_LOCATION (const line_map *map)
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: In function ‘MAP_START_LOCATION’:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:641:13: error: request for member ‘start_location’ in something not a structure or union
  641 |   return map->start_location;
      |             ^~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: At top level:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:647:42: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_ordinary’
  647 | ORDINARY_MAP_STARTING_LINE_NUMBER (const line_map_ordinary *ord_map)
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: In function ‘ORDINARY_MAP_STARTING_LINE_NUMBER’:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:649:17: error: request for member ‘to_line’ in something not a structure or union
  649 |   return ord_map->to_line;
      |                 ^~
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h: At top level:
../.././libcpp/include/line-map.h:658:40: error: unknown type name ‘line_map_ordinary’
  658 | ORDINARY_MAP_IN_SYSTEM_HEADER_P (const line_map_ordinary *ord_map)
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Final:

```sh
make[3]: *** [Makefile:226: charset.o] Error 1
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2955: all-build-libcpp] Error 2
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:29328: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/gcc12/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:1008: all] Error 2
```

***Makefile***:

```
# Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.
# Makefile for libcpp.  Run 'configure' to generate Makefile from Makefile.in

# Copyright (C) 2004-2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

#This file is part of libcpp.

#libcpp is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
#any later version.

#libcpp is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#GNU General Public License for more details.

#You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#along with libcpp; see the file COPYING3.  If not see
#<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.



srcdir = ../.././libcpp
top_builddir = .
VPATH = ../.././libcpp
INSTALL = /bin/ginstall -c
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = cru
ACLOCAL = /gcc12/gcc/missing aclocal
AUTOCONF = /gcc12/gcc/missing autoconf
AUTOHEADER = /gcc12/gcc/missing autoheader
CATALOGS = $(patsubst %,po/%,)
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2
WARN_CFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wc++-compat -pedantic -Wno-long-long 
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
WARN_CXXFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long 
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS = 
EXEEXT = 
GMSGFMT = 
INCINTL = 
INSTALL_DATA = /bin/ginstall -c -m 644
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /bin/ginstall -c
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /bin/ginstall -c
LDFLAGS = 
LIBICONV = 
LIBINTL = 
PACKAGE = cpplib
RANLIB = ranlib
SHELL = /bin/sh
USED_CATALOGS = 
XGETTEXT = 
CCDEPMODE = @CCDEPMODE@
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
DEPDIR = .deps
NOEXCEPTION_FLAGS = -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
PICFLAG = 
CET_HOST_FLAGS = 

datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
datadir = ${datarootdir}
exec_prefix = /usr/local
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
localedir = $(datadir)/locale
prefix = /usr/local

MSGMERGE = msgmerge
mkinstalldirs = $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/../mkinstalldirs
depcomp = $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/../depcomp

INCLUDES = -I$(srcdir) -I. -I$(srcdir)/../include  \
    -I$(srcdir)/include

ALL_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(WARN_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(PICFLAG) \
    $(CET_HOST_FLAGS)
ALL_CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) $(WARN_CXXFLAGS) $(NOEXCEPTION_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
    $(CPPFLAGS) $(PICFLAG) $(CET_HOST_FLAGS)

# The name of the compiler to use.
COMPILER = $(CXX)
COMPILER_FLAGS = $(ALL_CXXFLAGS)
DEPMODE = $(CXXDEPMODE)


libcpp_a_OBJS = charset.o directives.o errors.o \
    expr.o files.o identifiers.o init.o lex.o line-map.o macro.o \
    mkdeps.o pch.o symtab.o traditional.o

libcpp_a_SOURCES = charset.c directives.c errors.c \
    expr.c files.c identifiers.c init.c lex.c line-map.c macro.c \
    mkdeps.c pch.c symtab.c traditional.c

all: libcpp.a $(USED_CATALOGS)

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .gmo .o .obj .po .pox

libcpp.a: $(libcpp_a_OBJS)
    -rm -f libcpp.a
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) libcpp.a $(libcpp_a_OBJS)
    $(RANLIB) libcpp.a

# Rules to rebuild the configuration

Makefile: $(srcdir)/Makefile.in config.status
    $(SHELL) ./config.status Makefile

config.status: $(srcdir)/configure
    $(SHELL) ./config.status --recheck

$(srcdir)/configure: # $(srcdir)/aclocal.m4
    cd $(srcdir) && $(AUTOCONF)

$(srcdir)/aclocal.m4: # $(srcdir)/../config/acx.m4 \
    $(srcdir)/../config/gettext-sister.m4 $(srcdir)/../config/iconv.m4 \
    $(srcdir)/../config/codeset.m4 $(srcdir)/../config/lib-ld.m4 \
    $(srcdir)/../config/lib-link.m4 $(srcdir)/../config/lib-prefix.m4 \
    $(srcdir)/../config/override.m4 $(srcdir)/../config/proginstall.m4 \
    $(srcdir)/configure.ac
    cd $(srcdir) && $(ACLOCAL) -I ../config

config.h: stamp-h1
    test -f config.h || (rm -f stamp-h1 && $(MAKE) stamp-h1)

stamp-h1: $(srcdir)/config.in config.status
    -rm -f stamp-h1
    $(SHELL) ./config.status config.h

$(srcdir)/config.in: # $(srcdir)/configure.ac
    cd $(srcdir) && $(AUTOHEADER)
    -rm -f stamp-h1

# It is not possible to get LOCALEDIR defined in config.h because
# the value it needs to be defined to is only determined in the
# Makefile.  Hence we do this instead.
localedir.h: localedir.hs; @true
localedir.hs: Makefile
    echo "#define LOCALEDIR \"$(localedir)\"" > localedir.new
    $(srcdir)/../move-if-change localedir.new localedir.h
    echo timestamp > localedir.hs

# Installation rules and other phony targets

# These rule has to look for .gmo modules in both srcdir and
# the cwd, and has to check that we actually have a catalog
# for each language, in case they weren't built or included
# with the distribution.
installdirs:
    @$(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$(datadir); \
    cats="$(CATALOGS)"; for cat in $$cats; do \
      lang=`basename $$cat | sed 's/\.gmo$$//'`; \
      if [ -f $$cat ] || [ -f $(srcdir)/$$cat ]; then \
        dir=$(localedir)/$$lang/LC_MESSAGES; \
        $(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$$dir || exit 1; \
      fi; \
    done

install-strip install: all installdirs
    cats="$(CATALOGS)"; for cat in $$cats; do \
      lang=`basename $$cat | sed 's/\.gmo$$//'`; \
      if [ -f $$cat ]; then :; \
      elif [ -f $(srcdir)/$$cat ]; then cat=$(srcdir)/$$cat; \
      else continue; \
      fi; \
      dir=$(localedir)/$$lang/LC_MESSAGES; \
      echo $(INSTALL_DATA) $$cat $(DESTDIR)$$dir/$(PACKAGE).mo; \
      $(INSTALL_DATA) $$cat $(DESTDIR)$$dir/$(PACKAGE).mo; \
    done

mostlyclean:
    -rm -f *.o

clean: mostlyclean
    -rm -rf libcpp.a $(srcdir)/autom4te.cache

distclean: clean
    -rm -f config.h stamp-h1 config.status config.cache config.log \
      configure.lineno configure.status.lineno Makefile localedir.h \
      localedir.hs $(DEPDIR)/*.Po
    -rmdir $(DEPDIR)

maintainer-clean: distclean
    @echo "This command is intended for maintainers to use"
    @echo "it deletes files that may require special tools to rebuild."
    -rm -f $(srcdir)/configure $(srcdir)/aclocal.m4

check:
installcheck:
dvi:
pdf:
html:
info:
install-info:
install-pdf:
install-man:
install-html:

update-po: $(CATALOGS:.gmo=.pox)

.PHONY: installdirs install install-strip mostlyclean clean distclean \
  maintainer-clean check installcheck dvi pdf html info install-info \
  install-man update-po install-html

# Dependency rule.
COMPILE.base = $(COMPILER) $(DEFS) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c
ifeq ($(DEPMODE),depmode=gcc3)
# Note that we put the dependencies into a .Tpo file, then move them
# into place if the compile succeeds.  We need this because gcc does
# not atomically write the dependency output file.
COMPILE = $(COMPILE.base) -o $@ -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo
POSTCOMPILE = @mv $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Po
else
COMPILE = source='$<' object='$@' libtool=no DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(DEPMODE) \
      $(depcomp) $(COMPILE.base)
# depcomp handles atomicity for us, so we don't need a postcompile
# step.
POSTCOMPILE =
endif

# Implicit rules and I18N

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

# N.B. We do not attempt to copy these into $(srcdir).
.po.gmo:
    $(mkinstalldirs) po
    $(GMSGFMT) --statistics -o $@ $<

# The new .po has to be gone over by hand, so we deposit it into
# build/po with a different extension.
# If build/po/$(PACKAGE).pot exists, use it (it was just created),
# else use the one in srcdir.
.po.pox:
    $(mkinstalldirs) po
    $(MSGMERGE) $< `if test -f po/$(PACKAGE).pot; \
                    then echo po/$(PACKAGE).pot; \
                    else echo $(srcdir)/po/$(PACKAGE).pot; fi` -o $@

# Rule for regenerating the message template.
$(PACKAGE).pot: po/$(PACKAGE).pot
po/$(PACKAGE).pot: $(libcpp_a_SOURCES)
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(srcdir)/po
    $(XGETTEXT) --default-domain=$(PACKAGE) \
      --keyword=_ --keyword=N_ \
      --keyword=cpp_error:3 \
      --keyword=cpp_warning:3 \
      --keyword=cpp_pedwarning:3 \
      --keyword=cpp_warning_syshdr:3 \
      --keyword=cpp_error_with_line:5 \
      --keyword=cpp_warning_with_line:5 \
      --keyword=cpp_pedwarning_with_line:5 \
      --keyword=cpp_warning_with_line_syshdr:5 \
      --keyword=cpp_errno:3 \
      --keyword=SYNTAX_ERROR --keyword=SYNTAX_ERROR2 \
      --copyright-holder="Free Software Foundation, Inc." \
      --msgid-bugs-address="https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/" \
      --language=c -o po/$(PACKAGE).pot.tmp $^
    sed 's:$(srcdir)/::g' <po/$(PACKAGE).pot.tmp >po/$(PACKAGE).pot
    rm po/$(PACKAGE).pot.tmp

TAGS_SOURCES = $(libcpp_a_SOURCES) internal.h system.h ucnid.h \
    include/cpplib.h include/line-map.h include/mkdeps.h include/symtab.h

TAGS: $(TAGS_SOURCES)
    cd $(srcdir) && etags $(TAGS_SOURCES)

# Tell versions [3.59,3.63) of GNU make to not export all variables.
# Otherwise a system limit (for SysV at least) may be exceeded.
.NOEXPORT:

# Dependencies
-include $(patsubst %.o, $(DEPDIR)/%.Po, $(libcpp_a_OBJS))

# Dependencies on generated headers have to be explicit.
init.o: localedir.h
```

¿Esto cómo se soluciona? De no poderse solucionar los 500 errores (aquí se muestran aproximadamente 50), al menos, ¿Cómo soluciono el primer error, o alguno de ellos?

Comment: Puedes compartir el makefile que estas usando?

Comment: @Pablochaches Sí, edité la pregunta.